# RAD (IBM) to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss, websphere-6.1, ibm-rad

I am doing the migration of my project from WAS 6.1 to JBossAs7. The IDE that we were working with was RAD from IBM. The migration is almost complete and now I have to configure the project on Eclipse (Kepler).

What is the best approach to complete this task?

I am asking this because when I look to the `.classpath` , `.project` files and the `.settings` folde which contain data that belongs to the IBM and WAS 6.1 libraries and settings.

Should I import the project in Eclipse and start changing the settings in the IDE or erase those settings in the files and then import the project?

Any other ways I could achieve this?

Comment: Seems to me it will be simplest and fastest to just reconfigure directly in Eclipse rather than trying to reuse and edit the files.

Answer (score 0):

RAD comes with its own JDK and you will have to reconfigure the .classpath. Because server runtimes and jres will be different while configuring in eclipse. You can still reuse the .classpath for the rest of your projects.